# Switch Inputfield with a clickable Icon

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I Have the following input field, when clicking on the icon, the input field should be switch to another input id and label name. When clicking again, it should change back again. I have currently solved that with 2 seperate *.html files and switching between them. I'm now searching for a smarter solution.

```
 <ion-content>
      <div class="item-input-wrapper">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Your name</ion-label>
        <ion-input id="name" type="text"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon ion-button (click)="changeToStudentNumber()"  name="ios-switch"  clear item-right></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
```

Second html looks like:

```
 <ion-content>
      <div class="item-input-wrapper">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Your student number</ion-label>
        <ion-input id="studentnumber" type="text"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon ion-button (click)="changeToName()"  name="ios-switch"  clear item-right></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ngIf?

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="item-input-wrapper">
  <ion-item *ngIf="useName">
    <ion-label stacked>Your name</ion-label>
    <ion-input #nameInput id="name" type="text"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon ion-button (click)="toggleUseName(nameInput)"  name="ios-switch"  clear item-right></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="!useName">
    <ion-label stacked>Your student number</ion-label>
    <ion-input #numberInput id="studentnumber" type="text"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon ion-button (click)="toggleUseName(numberInput)"  name="ios-switch"  clear item-right></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>     
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The `toggleUseName()` can then just flip the `useName` property on your controller like this;

```
toggleUserName(inputToFocus) {
    this.useName = !this.useName;
    inputToFocus.setFocus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked great.  I did it like: `toggleUseName()
{

  if (this.useName) {
  this.useName = false;
  } else {
  this.useName = true;
  }
}`  - would you recommend that?

Comment: That would work, but can be done even simpler. I've edited the post to include a small sample of the `toggleUseName()` function.

Comment: Sorry, I have another question. Is it also possible after toggling that the input field get auto-focused?

Comment: I've edited the answer, I'm pretty sure that will do it (notice the #...) on the inputs and the parameter to the `toggleUseName()` call in the html, as well as the changed implementation for the `toggleUseName()` function.

Comment: This didn't work for me the focus get lost after switching.